# Хранение токена авторизации в SharedPreferences

Tags: android, api, android-shared-preferences, token

Вот файл, где я пишу save и get , но до этого я делал это для юзера, сейчас написал save для Data, подскажите правильно ли я сохранил, и как мне теперь написать get, чтоб в файле api отправить запрос в таком формате, чтоб вместо {{token}} вставлялся мой сохраненной токен.

```
@GET("users?token={{token}}")
    Call<UsersResponse>getData();
}

package com.example.diplomprogect.storage;

import android.content.Context; import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import com.example.diplomprogect.models.Data; import com.example.diplomprogect.models.User;

public class SharedPrefManager {

private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME ="my_shared_preff";

private static SharedPrefManager mInstance;
private Context mCtx;

private SharedPrefManager(Context mCtx){
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
}

public static synchronized SharedPrefManager getInstance(Context mCtx){
    if (mInstance == null){
        mInstance = new SharedPrefManager(mCtx);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public void saveUser(User user){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putInt("id", user.getId());
    editor.putString("login", user.getLogin());
    editor.putString("NickName", user.getNickname());

    editor.apply();
}

**public void saveData(Data data){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("token", data.getToken());
    editor.apply();
}**

public boolean isLoggedIn(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getInt("id", -1) != -1;
}

public User getUser(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return new User(
            sharedPreferences.getInt("id", -1),
            sharedPreferences.getString("login", null),
            sharedPreferences.getString("nickname", null)
    );
}

public void clear(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.apply();
}
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а где у вас собственно попытка сохранить? Я вижу только модель ответа от сервера

Comment: В интернете полно примеров кода как сохранить в SharedPreferences. Берите любой и пишите куда вам надо.

Comment: Извините, подскажите, пожалуйста, хороший пример, я,просто, начинаю только изучать и мне тяжело понять что именно надо сделать. Вот я получаю ответ от сервера, дальше мне нужно в файле с Preference попробовать сохранить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы получаете токен с сервера. Дальше вы его хотите сохранить как-то. Для этого нужно использовать [SharedPreferenes](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) так как это будет наиболее нормальный вариант. Так как вы не выложили код того как вы обращаетесь к серверу и как вытаскиваете токен, то я покажу как сохранить строку в памяти. Для этого вы должны в месте где получаете токен провести запись данных:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("token", "string_token").apply();
```

Дальше в месте где вам нужен токен вы должны его вытащить из памяти:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String token= prefs.getString("token", ""); // "" - это значение по-умолчанию если токен не сохранен
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, и извините за глупый вопрос, но вместо MY_PREFS_NAME писать  любое имя или какое то определённое? И обязательно использовать тот файл где я получаю токен (это получается файл авторизации, где я по api от сервера получаю логин пароль и токен) или нужен отдельный файл  SharedPreferenes? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: И ещё, мне нужен этот токен, чтоб по api отправить запрос на сервер, я могу использовать вторую часть того кода что вы прислали, перед запросом get в файле api?

Comment: в имени можете писать что угодно, что значит использовать тот файл где вы получаете токен, это не очень понятно, вы создаете один файл с настройками приложения, и там все сохраняете, да вы можете использовать вторую часть кода, она для этого там и написана)

Comment: Просто я имею в виду, что у меня несколько файлов, регистрация, авторизация и тд. И токен мне выдаёт сервер при авторизации, то есть мне первую часть кода нужно писать в LoginActivity? Спасибо вам большое, вы очень помогли)

Comment: да вероятнее всего на экране логина

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста мой ответ ниже, правильно ли я сохранил? Извините если запутал, не хватает опыта, чтоб лучше ориентироваться, сам путаюсь во всех этих файлах, пока. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: в таких случаях лучше редактировать свой вопрос, чем добавлять ответ :)